# Should I call evhttp_request_free to release resource in http server?

Tags: http, free, libevent

I use libevent2.1.1 to write a simple http server, I think I should release `evhttp_request` with `evhttp_request_free` in `http_server_callback`. but when I run it, error happened. Please tell me why, and what I should do.

[image]

```
void http_server_callback (struct evhttp_request *req, void *arg)
{
    evhttp_send_reply (req, HTTP_OK, "OK", NULL);

    evhttp_request_free(req);
}

int http_server_run (void)
{ 
    struct event_base *base;
    struct evhttp *http;
    struct evhttp_bound_socket *handle;

    base = event_base_new ();
    if (! base)
    { 
        fprintf (stderr, "Couldn't create an event_base: exiting\n");
        return 1;
    }

    http = evhttp_new (base);
    if (! http)
    { 
        fprintf (stderr, "couldn't create evhttp. Exiting.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    evhttp_set_gencb (http, http_server_callback, NULL);

    handle = evhttp_bind_socket_with_handle (http, "127.0.0.1", 8888);
    if (! handle)
    { 
        fprintf (stderr, "couldn't bind to port 8888. Exiting.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    event_base_dispatch (base);

    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{ 
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup (0x101, &WSAData);

    http_server_run();

    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: show the full code and the error detail.

Comment: thanks, jfly! I modifid the problem, and post full code and error graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `req` will be freed in the callback function `evhttp_send_done` when server finishes writing. So it results in a double free.
the source code in libevent:

```
static void
evhttp_send_done(struct evhttp_connection *evcon, void *arg)
{
    int need_close;
    struct evhttp_request *req = TAILQ_FIRST(&evcon->requests);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(&evcon->requests, req, next);

    need_close =
        (REQ_VERSION_BEFORE(req, 1, 1) &&
        !evhttp_is_connection_keepalive(req->input_headers))||
        evhttp_is_connection_close(req->flags, req->input_headers) ||
        evhttp_is_connection_close(req->flags, req->output_headers);

    EVUTIL_ASSERT(req->flags & EVHTTP_REQ_OWN_CONNECTION);
    evhttp_request_free(req);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another problem, I use bufferevent for socket communication, but I can't receive an BEV_EVENT_EOF, Now I use shutdown() function, but it cause an error. How can I close bufferevent normally.  evutil_socket_t fd = bufferevent_getfd(bev); shutdown(fd, 1);

Comment: don't know how you exactly use it, just ask another question and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: hi, jfly, this is the problem site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521992/how-to-close-bufferevent-normally